# Best way to add custom scripts in Angular project (Materialize example)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I use Materialize - css and js framework in project with mean technology based on Angular 6. I need to add modal materialize component, which require js initialization code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
  });
```

In which place should I contain this code? Paste code in onInit component function is not working. Modal should be used in one of the Angular components.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in a separate file in Javascript.

Place it in your `assets` folder.

In your `angular.json` file, find the assets :

```
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ],
```

You should find a `scripts` property right under it, add your script to it :

```
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/my-script.js"
        ]
```

Your script won't be minified and will be ran when your application is built.